# How can I vertically align a div without giving the height of the screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, positioning

I am trying to build a slider which is aligned horizontally and vertically.
I am using `display: flex;` in this code:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">

  the content

</div>
```

I want the div to be in the center of the screen but without giving the body a certain height this doesn't seem to work for me. Do I have to use `height: 100vh;` or is there a much better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `height: 100%` on `html` also.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  the content
</div>
```

Comment: Damn, I seemed to be blind. Thanks for your help. Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make body flex. Use a container instead:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  /*or use height:100vh;*/
}



<div class="container">
    <div id="slider">

      the content

    </div>
  </div>
```